# What is a solid iptables configuration for my desktop?

Tags: iptables, firewall

On my desktop, I want to configure iptables pretty strictly. I see no reason why I need to allow anything except for internet traffic that I initiated. And maybe even that could be limited to only a few ports. What are the basic rules that can close off my desktop? I only need:

- To browse the internet
- Download email

Any recommended set of rules?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iptables: allow certain ips and block all other connection](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11851/iptables-allow-certain-ips-and-block-all-other-connection)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following rules will allow all outgoing connections, but block any incoming connections. The INPUT and FORWARD chains are set to reject packets by default, the OUTPUT chain is set to accept packets by default, and the last rule allows incoming packets which are part of existing connections (which in this case can only be outgoing connections).

```
iptables --policy INPUT DROP
iptables --policy FORWARD DROP
iptables --policy OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables --append INPUT --match state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED --jump ACCEPT
iptables --append INPUT --jump REJECT
iptables --append FORWARD --jump REJECT
```

If you want to restrict outgoing traffic you want to change the OUTPUT policy to reject, and add rules to accept traffic on certain ports. For example:

```
iptables --policy OUTPUT DROP
iptables --append OUTPUT --protocol udp --match multiport --dports domain,bootps --jump ACCEPT
iptables --append OUTPUT --protocol tcp --match multiport --dports domain,http,https,ssh,pop3s,imaps,submission --jump ACCEPT
iptables --append OUTPUT --jump REJECT
```

Comment: `REJECT` is not a valid policy target (`ACCEPT`, `DROP`, `QUEUE`, and `RETURN` are the only ones allowed there).

Comment: Is `iptables --append OUTPUT --jump REJECT` supposed to be `iptables --append OUTPUT --jump DROP`?  or remain "REJECT"?  All the `--jump`s still show "REJECT"

Comment: @killermist I prefer using explicit rejects in my firewalls instead of silent drops, hence the REJECT rules in addition to the DROP policies.

Comment: After the previously mentioned valid policy list, I wasn't sure if "REJECT" was a valid policy, or not.  Not a criticism question, just valid curiosity.

Comment: @killermist I'm not using it as a *policy* anymore, but as a *jump target*.

Comment: This may be beyond the scope of the original question, but "How does that work?"  I don't see a `--policy OUTPUT REJECT` (or something similar, I'm not familiar with the syntax) in any of the above.

Comment: you should also allow loopback packets `sudo iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT`
`sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT`

Answer (score 2):

The following `iptables-restore` script should suffice for your needs:

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state ! --state NEW -j DROP
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

The script can be made even shorter by dropping the rule that allows ICMP pings, but I wouldn't recommend doing that. IMO, responding to ping doesn't hurt security much (if at all), and it can be helpful for network troubleshooting.

If you want to allow incoming connections on a particular TCP port (e.g. to allow `ssh` connections), you could add rule(s) to your script, such as the following, right above the `COMMIT` statement:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 --syn -j ACCEPT
```