# blocking all traffic except whitelisted ip adresses

Tags: ubuntu, firewall

I need block all incoming and outcoming connections in firewall, except ip adresses i whitelist. I am currently on virtual machine using ubuntu.
I tried these commands from [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11851/iptables-allow-certain-ips-and-block-all-other-connection) site:
but i cant connect to this website, which is google, but ping works, i have no experience with linux, other websites don't work aswell.

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 172.217.23.206 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 172.217.23.206 -j ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

Comment: This will work but if you're going to access this website via FQDN you'll need to add it to `/etc/hosts`.

Answer (score 9):

[`iptables`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables) works on a first match basis. Let's break down your example:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 172.217.23.206 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 172.217.23.206 -j ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

The first line tells `iptables` to permit all traffic from the IP address `172.217.23.206` to the machine where these rules where applied. And all traffic is, quite literally, *all traffic*. So, no matter the protocol, port, options, et cetera; as long as the source matches `172.217.23.206` it passes.

The second line permits all any and all traffic from your machine to `172.217.23.206`. Again, it doesn't matter what the protocol, port, etc is; as long as the destination matches `172.217.23.206` it is allowed.

The third line tells `iptables` to *drop* any incoming traffic that doesn't match the first two rules, whereas the fourth and last line tells `iptables` to *drop* any outgoing traffic that doesn't match the three foregoing lines.

---

I am assuming you want to build a scenario that allows traffic to only a couple of websites. The ruleset you have written, isn't going to work for this scenario;

- Your computer has no way of knowing that google.com might resolve to `172.217.23.206`. Normally, it can acquire this information by querying a DNS server or by local `/etc/hosts` entries.
- There is no reason to allow any incoming traffic in this scenario, as `iptables` is smart enough to keep track of your connections and to allow replies. This process is calling keeping state.
- Allowing all kinds of traffic to `172.217.23.206`, just to get a website doesn't make any sense.
- ICMP traffic (including `ping`) is a special kind. You need to block it specifically.

---

This ruleset does fit this scenario:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d unix.stackexchange.com --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d unix.stackexchange.com --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

This ruleset allows your computer to query DNS servers, using port 53/udp. It then permits TCP traffic to unix.stackexchange.com, to port 80 (http) and 443 (https). It keeps track of connections and drops all other traffic.

You could drop the rule permitting DNS queries, as long as you've configured the matching entries in `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: An edit *and* an upvote!  **;-)**

Comment: produces error iptables v1.6.1:  host/network `-----' not found

Comment: used to work earlier

Comment: does not work now

Comment: And when you allow DNS, you allow to access pretty much the entire Internet. https://www.google.com/search?q=DNS+tunnel Lastly, only UDP over port 53 is not sufficient nowadays. Certain DNS queries don't work over UDP alone.

Comment: would this work sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m string --string "unix.stackexchange.com" --algo kmp --dport 80 -j  ACCEPT

Comment: to allow certain sites. Currently this answer just blocks  every thing

Comment: @TejasShetty  This will **not** work. HTTPS encrypts (SNI aside) all the data so this rule will never produce any matches.

Comment: Allowing DNS queries (UDP dport 53 rule) is not necessary if you add the destination server to your /etc/hosts file. If we are talking about `unix.stackexchange.com` alone this rule is not sufficient as the website uses multiple other websites to render and work properly. At the very least `sstatic.net` and `stackexchange.com` are required. Lastly, considering that many websites are behind CDNs nowadays, such simple iptables rules may and will break quite often.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov  can you post your comment as an answer so that I can award you for your work