# IP Tables - Blocking Incoming Traffic

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firewall

This question is in a way related [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11851/iptables-allow-certain-ips-and-block-all-other-connection) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/478735/blocking-all-traffic-except-whitelisted-ip-adresses?noredirect=1&lq=1)

My question is about blocking incoming connections using iptables. I read different posts in unix.stackexchange.com and got a basic understanding of iptables. But I do not understand some particular points. Any help is appreciated.

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT                              
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

I wanna use this code. It has to block all incoming connections (all ports will be closed for an outsider) except the responses for requests sent by me. This was simple I thought.

1. will incoming ICMP ping requests be blocked by the above shown code ? If not, why?
2. if above shown code does not block ICMP ping requests, adding `iptables -I INPUT -j DROP -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request` will block it?
3. can port scans from a blocked ip can get information about my computer?
4. should I add specific rules like `-p tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN FIN,SYN -j DROP` to block specific flood attacks or my first code handles it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes. All inbound traffic that isn't post of an existing session will be blocked
2. - 
3. Only if (a) you've connected to that rogue host, or (b) it knows you should be there and by your lack if response it can infer you've a firewall
4. You're already covered by #1

Answer (score 1):

@roaima's answer is good, but only so long as you don't start allowing some things.

I would recommend:

1. I would put an explicit DROP rule in.  It should be last.

   ```
   iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
   ```

   Mind you, set the policy too.
2. If you ever plan to allow some input (like SSH or a web server), put your #4 before any ALLOWs.
   Also block other bad things, like fragments.
3. Your point 2 is correct, but only for IPv4.  IPv6 has a different ping.  And (classically) a different set of filters.
4. Don't forget to filter IPv6 too.