# IPTables - Allow only traffic from specific ranges

Tags: iptables

I am trying to block all traffic to a webserver except from some defined subnets. I've checked numerous posts and believed I had iptables set correctly but for some reason the site is still accessible outside the subnets i've defined in the ruleset. Is anyone able to shed some light on what I may have done wrong? I've established that removing rule 3 stops the site from being reachable at all. The site itself sits in 10.10.0.0/16.

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     10.10.0.0/16         anywhere            
2        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     172.30.0.0/16        anywhere            
3        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    lo      anywhere             anywhere
```

The goal will be to add various whitelisted public IPs and lockdown the site so that it is only accessible to some.

Rules were added as follows:

```
iptables -I INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -s 10.10.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -s 172.30.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

Comment: With nftables it is much easier.

Answer (score 0):

The **rule order** matters in iptables. By using `iptables -A` you are appending rules *at the end* of the ruleset. But `iptables -I` inserts a rule on top of the ruleset, unless you specify a line number (you haven't). As a result rules are not evaluated in the intended order.

Here is a sample configuration that should work, based on [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11870/190343). Flush your rules before to avoid duplication.

```
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 10.10.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 172.30.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
# add some more whitelisting rules here
iptables -P INPUT DROP # Drop everything we don't accept
```

The third rule is important:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

otherwise your server will not get replies to the connections that it initiated, take for example DNS requests.

On a side note, iptables works for IPv4 but not IPv6, so if your server is IPv6-enabled you may have clients connecting using **IPv6**. This is possible if they are connecting by hostname instead of IP address, and that the hostname resolves to a valid IPv6 address on your server. You'd probably be aware though, but many people are still not aware that iptables does filter IPv6 traffic (and attacks).
I would then also add similar `ip6tables` rules if appropriate for your setup.